# How to rearrange this Dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Everyone. I used this code to create a dataframe.

```
library(wbstats)
library(dplyr)

pakistan_data <- wb(country = "PK", indicator = c("SM.POP.NETM", "MS.MIL.XPND.CD", "FP.CPI.TOTL", "SE.XPD.TOTL.GD.ZS", "GB.XPD.RSDV.GD.ZS", "GC.XPN.TOTL.GD.ZS"), startdate = 2010, enddate = 2020)
```

Then i used tidyr to sort the data according to the indicators.

```
library(tidyr)

pakistan_data_wide <- pakistan_data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = indicator, values_from = value)
```

The problem is that that resulting dataframe has multiple years. How can i consolidate them and get rid of blanks so that each year has the indicators data infront of it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKy1k.png)

I want the data to be sorted year wise.

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you create a few rows showing what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @LMc Presently Dataset is like this  (https://imgur.com/FAGJ6Pw) . I want it to be like this. (https://imgur.com/PbNoZCE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the pivot with instructions on how to pivot wider (e.g., what values to keep in what rows). So, you need to specify the `id_cols` argument:

```
library(tidyr)

pakistan_data |>
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(iso3c, date, iso2c, country),
    names_from = indicator,
    values_from = value)
```

If you need to sort pipe to `dplyr::arrange`.

**Output**

```
  iso3c date  iso2c country  `Net migration` `Military expenditure (current USD)` `Consumer price index (2010 = 100)` Government expenditure on education, total (%~1 Resea~2
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>              <dbl>                                <dbl>                               <dbl>                                           <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 PAK   2020  PK    Pakistan         -588736                         10394502555.                                200.                                            2.37  NA    
 2 PAK   2019  PK    Pakistan        -1177218                         10388318165.                                182.                                            2.51   0.201
 3 PAK   2018  PK    Pakistan        -1309609                         11732131762.                                165.                                            2.60  NA    
 4 PAK   2017  PK    Pakistan        -1574581                         11461253917.                                157.                                            2.90   0.236
 5 PAK   2016  PK    Pakistan        -2290411                          9973768059.                                151.                                            3.00  NA    
 6 PAK   2015  PK    Pakistan        -2172159                          9483482373.                                145.                                            2.65   0.246
 7 PAK   2014  PK    Pakistan        -2037911                          8654923192.                                142.                                            2.47  NA    
 8 PAK   2013  PK    Pakistan        -1906315                          7645455529.                                132.                                            2.49   0.293
 9 PAK   2012  PK    Pakistan        -1647986                          7478971082.                                123.                                            2.14  NA    
10 PAK   2011  PK    Pakistan         -890633                          6954787511.                                112.                                            2.22   0.329
11 PAK   2010  PK    Pakistan         -431891                          5974613176.                                100                                             2.29  NA
```